# Making and writing to new buffer

Tags: buffers

Have been playing for some time with buffers.  With this code I can make a new buffer called `Corona` and insert some text in it.  Now I would like to pass the buffer name to `bufr-message` rather than having it hardwired to use `corona-bufr`.  Together with a function that appends text to an existing buffer.  Would it be better to have a single function that writes to a specific buffer and if the buffer does not exist, it is made?

```
(defvar coronas-bufr "*Corona*")

(defun bufr-message (message)
   "Inserts formatted string into the dedicated buffer."

   (with-current-buffer
       (get-buffer-create corona-bufr)
     (insert message)) )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`get-buffer-create` can take a string as the buffer name, thus you can pass the buffer name to the function.

> get-buffer-create is a built-in function in ‘C source code’.
>
> (get-buffer-create BUFFER-OR-NAME &optional INHIBIT-BUFFER-HOOKS)
>
> Return the buffer specified by BUFFER-OR-NAME, creating a new one if needed.
> If BUFFER-OR-NAME is a string and a live buffer with that name exists,
> return that buffer.  If no such buffer exists, create a new buffer with
> that name and return it.

```
(defun bufr-message (bufname message)
   "Inserts formatted string MESSAGE into the dedicated buffer named BUFNAME."

   (with-current-buffer
     (get-buffer-create bufname)
     (insert message)))
```

I don't know wether there is a built-in function that inserts text to a buffer (and creates the buffer if it does not exist), but I think you can write one if you like. :)